# ifstream how to start read line from a particular line using c++

Tags: c++, ifstream, seekg

I'm using `ifstream` to parse a file in a c++ code. I'm not able using `seekg()` and `tellg()` to jump in a particular line of the code.

In particular I would like to read a line, with method getLine, from a particular position of the file. Position saved in the previously iteration.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Position saved in the previously iteration."*?  In what sense are you iterating?  If you're iterating over the file, you can call `getline(my_ifstream, my_string)` to read each line in turn.  If you have an integral line number and wish to jump to that line from an effectively unrelated position in the file, you need to read from some known-line position (e.g. line 1 at position 0) and tally up the newlines as you go.

Comment: @TonyD Yes, I'm iterating over the file, but at some point I stop and work in another file. Then after that, I would like to restart from the last line read before using 'getline(my_ifstream, my_string)'  with the first file.

Comment: each `ifstream` maintains its own input position - if you use different `ifstream` objects for the different files, you can continue reading lines where you left off in the first file without any complications.  If you really want to use the same `ifstream`, you can call [`tellg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) to get the current position, and `seekg` later to restore it.

Comment: @TonyD Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to skip required number of lines.
The best way to do it is ignoring strings with std::istream::ignore

```
for (int currLineNumber = 0; currLineNumber < startLineNumber; ++currLineNumber){
    if (addressesFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), addressesFile.widen('\n'))){
        //just skipping the line
    } else {
        // todo: handle the error
    }
}
```

The first argument is maximum number of characters to extract. If this is exactly numeric_limits::max(), there is no limit.

You should use is instead of std::getline due to better performance.

Comment: So, I should use this to jump a total number of line and then call `getLine ` to read the next line. Is this right?

Comment: @Mattia, yes, you are right. You need to read out as many lines as required to archive the line you want to read. The file itself does not contain any meta(auxiliary)-data which could help to jump directly to the required position. If you do not collect such meta-data by yourself, counting lines when reading out is the only way. The essential fact is that using _ignore_ instead of _getline_ is much more efficient.

Comment: Perfect, it seems to work properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are no specific C++ functions, like "seekline", for your needs, and I see two ways to solve this task:

1. Preliminary you can expand every line in textfile with spaces to reach a
   constant length *L*. Than, to seek required line *N*, just use
   `seekg` with *L* * *N* offset.
2. This method is more complicated. You can create an auxiliary binary
   file, every byte of it will keep length of every line of source
   file. This auxiliary file is a kind of database. Next, you have to
   load this binary file into array in your program within initialization phase. The offset of a
   required line in textfile should be calculated as sum of first *N* array's
   elements. Of course, it's necessary to update an auxiliary file and source file simultaneously.

The first case is more efficient if a textfile is loyal for it's size requirements. The second case brings best perfomance for long textfile and rare edit operations.